# WebStorm: Attribute [data-*] is not allowed here

Tags: html, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm currently working on a ReactJS project and can't get rid of this type of linting error, which is driving me crazy.

[image]

While it should be perfectly fine to use this attribute here, WebStorm keep saying that it's not allowed. How can I fix this?

### My WebStorm 2017.1 Settings

**Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript**
`React JSX` (JSX in EcmaScript 6)

**Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs > Default XML Schemas**
`HTML 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fixed for 2017.1.1 -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22667

Either wait for that version to be released or try EAP build if you wish -- it *should* contain the fix: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP